# How to conditionally run Github workflow action only for tags made on specific branch?

Tags: github-actions

I am using a couple different Github workflows including one that should only run on official releases.  Inside the `.github/workflows/release.yml` is this `on` condition:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'
```

However, this can still run if someone on our team accidentally (or purposely) pushes a tag from the `develop` branch.  Ideally, we would want to lock this down so that the tag MUST be on the `main` branch (since that is protected), and maybe even further, it would be nice if we could ensure that the tags are only referencing the specific merge commit relating to the corresponding release.  For example, if I run

```
git branch --contains tags/v1.2.3
```

this would normally output the `main` branch where I made the tag.  Can I add a condition to the github workflow to check the output of that?

Looking at the [Github action documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags) it is not clear if multiple conditions are evaluated using a logical AND or a logical OR.

Answer (score 24):

The events types specified in `on` have a logical `OR` between them. So for example

```yaml
on:
  push:
    tags: ['v[0-9].[0-9]+.[0-9]+']
    branches: [master]
```

would unfortunately trigger the workflow for any matching tag on any branch but also any push on master with or without tags. I also updated the tag pattern following the example from the [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet).

You will have to decide if you want to run the workflow only for tags and then filter out anything else than master:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    tags: ['v[0-9].[0-9]+.[0-9]+']

jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    steps: [...]
```

or the other way around:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/v')
    steps: [...]
```

You might pick the second solution if, for example, your workflow contains other jobs that might run on pushes to master. As you will also notice, the filter of the tag is less accurate on the second one and it might become an issue. It is also important to note that you can skip whole workflows using the conditions in [`on`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on), whole jobs with [`jobs.<job_id>.if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif) but also just steps with [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsif)

Comment: I thought I had this working, but now that I've tried to repeat it in another repo and I can't get this to work with either option, either triggering on push of branches to `main` and checking `${{ startsWith('refs/tags/v', github.ref) }}` OR pushing tags and checking `${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}`.  Is there something more to this?

Comment: When the action is triggered by a push on tags, `github.ref` is something like `refs/tags/xxx`; when action is triggered by a push on branches, `github.ref` is `refs/heads/main`.  So this seems like a Catch-22: when I push a branch, I can't see the tag, when I push a tag, I can't see the branch.

Comment: You could maybe checkout master and use `git merge-base --is-ancestor $tag HEAD` when triggered from a tag push to check if the tag is present on the master branch.

Comment: awesome response it was very useful, I am editing as parameters of startWith where inverted. Thanks a lot for the answer @ITChap